# warranty repair with activation lock activated

Tags: restore, iphone, warranty, activation-lock

I just bought a 2nd hand broken iPhone5s which stuck at restore mode, restore failed every time. This phone is still under warranty,and i wanted to send it for repair but it's have be service from out of my country. So i would like to know does apple repair any phone that have activation lock on.

Comment: why don't you ask them? they make individual decision.

Answer (score 2):

If they replace the motherboard then you will need to add new apple account (activation lock will be turned off). But if they repair your phone you will need to enter your id & password.